# Emgu.CV on raspberry Pi - VideoCapture.Start() returns an exception

Tags: c#, camera, emgucv, raspberry-pi4

Some info: Trying to run RaspberryPi 4B and Camera V2 with Emgu.Cv. I have installed the 64 bit OS, installed the latest NuGet packages for Emgu.Cv and Emgu.Cv.Runtime.debian.arm64

I am stuck at trying to get the frames from the camera. I enabled the exception throwing by the VideoCapture and i got the following, unspecified errors:

Here is just some test code to try and capture image, the camera is up and running, i have capture it's video with Microsoft Iot and with Picam in python. Getting stuck here with Emgu.Cv:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace EmguCVApp

{
    class Program
    {
        static VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.V4L2);

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            // Setting a 640*480 24 fps capture

            capture.Set(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth, 1920);
            capture.Set(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 1080);
            capture.Set(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps, 30);
            capture.ExceptionMode = true;
            capture.ImageGrabbed += ImageReceived;
            capture.Start();
            Mat frame = new Mat();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (capture.Grab())
                    {
                        ;
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error Start {ex.Message} Error End");
                }
            }
        }



        private static void ImageReceived(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mat frame = new Mat();
            if (capture.Retrieve(frame))
            {
                CvInvoke.Imshow("Raspberry cam", frame);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dont mind the code, I am just trying to establish an image from the camera, but I get stuck here. The exception occurs calling the `capture.Start();`

[image]

Does any one have experience with something similar returning by the VideoCapture? Unfortunately, there really is not a lot of information about the Pi camera with Emgu.Cv on the internet and the exception is very generic with next to no info.

Side note, if I disable exception generation I do get online to the camera, I can confirm it is connected (trying to access it with CLI returns me an error, that the resouce is beeing used). It seem grabbing the image is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on trying to run 64 bit OS and swapped to 32 bit where it seems to work now. Though it wasn't all smooth sailing.